# CI based on docker-compose?

Tags: continuous-integration, docker-compose

I am currently building a little application that requires that some massively annoying software is installed and running in backround. To ease the pain of developing, I wrote a set of docker-compose files that runs the necessary daemons, creates some jobs, and throws in some test data.

Now, I'd like to run this in a CI-like manner. I currently have Jenkins check all the different repositories and execute a shell script that calles `docker-compose up --abort-on-container-exit`. That gets the job done, but it seems like a hack, and I'm not such a huge fan of Jenkins.

What I want to ask is: is there a more beautiful way of doing this? Specifically, is there a CI that will

- watch a set of git repositories,
- re-execute docker-compose (possibly multiple times with different sets of parameters), and
- nicely collect and split the logs and tell me which container exactly failed how?
- (Optionally) is not some cloud service but installable on my local server?

If the answer to this is "write a Jenkins module", then fine, so be it.
I'm aware that there are options like gitlab-ci, but I'd like to keep the CI script in a fashion that can also be easily executed during development, before pusing to a repo.